# C++: Student Record Program

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am in desperate need of help. I am supposed to create a student record using structs and vectors.
In the program, I should have:

1. For a given student, identified either by name or student number
   (a) Enter a new student into the record. (Assume no courses completed.)
   (b) Grade point average
   (c) Transcript, i.e. a list of courses taken, including credit value and grade earned
   (d) Record a newly completed course
2. A listing, sorted by name, of all students who have taken a given course.
3. A listing, sorted by grade point average, of all students and their grade point averages,
   who are on probation, i.e. have a grade point average < 2.0 .

This is what I have so far... and I seem to be having troubles with the user input how read it into my structs

```
using namespace std;

struct courses {
    string courseName;
    int courseNum;
    double credit;
    char grade;
};

struct students {
    string name;
    int id;
    vector<courses> c;
};

int main() {

    // variables
    string name;
    char selector;
    students s;
    courses d;
    vector<students> student;
    vector<courses> course;

    // (1) create a menu: (a) user input, (b) echo record (with overall gpa), (c) failed students
    do {
        // prompt for user input
        cout << "Enter Q to (Q)uit, (C)reate new student record, (S)how all record(s) on file, show students on (P)robation: ";
        cin >> selector;

        selector = toupper(selector);
        switch (selector) {



            // (a) ask and get for user input:
            // student info first
            // courses second
        case 'C':

            // variables within case C
            char answer;
            char answerAddAnotherCourseEntry;
            char answerToAnotherStudentRecord;

            do {


                cout << "Enter your name and student ID number: ";
                cin >> s.name >> s.id;
                student.push_back(s);

                do {
                    cout << "Do you want to create a student course entry ('y' or 'n')? ";
                    cin >> answer;
                    answer = toupper(answer);

                    cout << "Enter your course number, course name, grade received and credit worth: ";
                    cin >> d.courseNum >> d.courseName >> d.grade >> d.credit;
                    course.push_back(d);


                    cout << "Add another student course entry ('y' or 'n'): ";
                    cin >> answerAddAnotherCourseEntry;
                    answerAddAnotherCourseEntry = toupper(answerAddAnotherCourseEntry);


                } while (answer == 'N');

                cout << "Add another student record ('y' or 'n'): " << endl;
                cin >> answerToAnotherStudentRecord;
                answerAddAnotherCourseEntry = toupper(answerToAnotherStudentRecord);
            } while (answerToAnotherStudentRecord == 'N');
            break;


            // (b) echo record of vectors
            // sort by name
        case 'S':
            if (student.empty()) {
                cout << "\nSorry, no records exist in the database.";
            }
            else
                for (int count = 0; count < student.size(); count++) {         //For Loop to Display All Records

                    cout << "Student name: " << student[count].name << "ID Number: " << student[count].id << endl;
                    count++;

                    // another for loop i think
                    for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
                        cout << "Course info: " << " " << course[i].courseNum << " " << course[i].courseName << " " << course[i].credit << " " << course[i].grade << endl;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            cout << endl;
            break;


            // (c) separate failed student into another vector
            // sort by gpa
        case 'P':
            break;




        } // bracket closing switch
    } // bracket closing do while
    while (selector != 'q' && selector != 'Q');     // first do while
```

Comment: Edit the code into the post. There is a button for it.

Comment: Sorry, still super new to this! Just did it, thanks! :)

Comment: The next step now is to localize the problem and then try to solve it. It's fine if you can't do the latter (if you could you would solve it yourself), but probably very few people will go through that much code. So, try to shrink the code into minimal possible that reproduces the problem you're facing, and write what you expect and what you've tried

Comment: Pardon the obvious, but shouldn't `while (answer == 'N');` be `while (answer != 'N');` in your course-add logic? Shouldn't you want to continue adding courses until `N` is selected (i.e. keep looping so long as it is NOT `N`) ? Likewise for `while (answerToAnotherStudentRecord == 'N')`.

Answer (score 0):

The issues I see with your input is that you are trying to store the user input directly in a string, here e.g. in the variable `name` of the struct `s`:

```
cout << "Enter your name and student ID number: ";
cin >> s.name >> s.id;
```

This does not compile. Instead you can store the name in a temporary char array first and then copy it to `s.name`.

```
char studentName[128];
cout << "Enter your name and student ID number: ";
cin >> studentName >> s.id;
s.name = studentName;
```

You can also work with [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) if you want to store your input directly in  a string.

Furthermore you try to directly output the variable `student[count].name`, which is a string, to cout:

```
cout << "Student name: " << student[count].name << "ID Number: " << student[count].id << endl;
```

Converting the string to a char array first makes this compile:

```
cout << "Student name: " << student[count].name.c_str() << "ID Number: " << student[count].id << endl;
```